# How can I solve "NoSuchMethodError: The method "[]" was called on null."

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

`gamelist` is a String List of document names in the collection.
The `questionMap` value is an array named text field obtained from the firestore document using the `gamelist` value as key. I would like to update the `questionMap` when I press the pass button, but when I press the pass button, I get an error like the one in the title, and the map does not seem to be rewritten properly. It is a dirty code, but I would like to know how to solve it.

This is my code:

```dart
class PlayPage extends StatefulWidget {
  List gameList;
  Map questionMap;
  String category;
  int myScore;

  PlayPage({
    required this.gameList,
    required this.category,
    required this.myScore,
    required this.questionMap,
  });

  @override
  State<PlayPage> createState() => _PlayPageState();
}

class _PlayPageState extends State<PlayPage> {
  int quizNumber = 0;
  int listNumber = 0;
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  void changeQuiz() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Card(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: double.infinity,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 20, bottom: 200, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    widget.questionMap[widget.gameList[listNumber]][quizNumber],
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 10,
            bottom: 30,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    "Pass",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    listNumber += 1;
                    quizNumber = 0;
                    setState(
                      () {
                        var docRef = db
                            .collection(widget.category)
                            .doc(widget.gameList[listNumber]);
                        docRef.get().then(
                          (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
                            var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                            List questions = selectQuiz(
                              data["text"],
                            );
                            widget.questionMap = {
                              widget.gameList[listNumber]: questions
                            };
                            print(widget.questionMap);
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 30),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 70,
                  height: 70,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor:
                        (quizNumber < 9) ? Colors.teal : Colors.grey,
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (quizNumber < 9) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            quizNumber += 1;
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where the error pointed out to?

Comment: Looks like if there is no value, a null is returned instead of an empty list. Check for null before you reference the list with [].

Comment: Sorry for late reply. There seems to be a problem with the PlayPage widget. I want to update the map by pressing the "pass" button, but when the map goes outside of "then", it is empty.

Comment: Thanks for comment.When I print in this code the map is not empty.